# How to align decimal points when using cases statement

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cases

I have a statement like

```
\begin{equations*}
\begin{cases}
{\zeta}_{A} = -10.1234567 \cdots, \\
{\zeta}_{B} = 1{,}001.2345678 \cdots.
\end{cases}
\end{equations*}
```

How do I align the decimal points with the equations being left justified and the case spacing remaining unaffected.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 12):

A solution that uses an `array` environment; note that using a `cases` environment seems like overkill for the case (pun intended) at hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{} r @{{}={}} r}
\zeta_A & -10.1234567\cdots,\\
\zeta_B & 1{,}001.2345678\cdots.\\
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The preceding solution assumes that both numbers have the same number of digits following the decimal marker. If this assumption isn't valid, the following modified solution, which still uses an `array` environment but now employs three rather than just two columns, should work for you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{} r @{{}={}} r @{.} l}
\zeta_A     &     -10 & 1234\cdots,\\
\zeta_{BCD} & 1{,}001 & 12345678901 \cdots.\\
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: but this works as desired only if you've got the same number of digits following the decimal point.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks. I've posted an addendum to provide a solution that works in the general case.

Answer (score 4):

Some `\phantom`s can be used to push content into the appropriate location. Overlapping allows also for accommodating for the use of `\phantom`s.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  A &= \begin{cases}
    \zeta_A = -10.1234567 \cdots, \\
    \zeta_B = 1{,}001.2345678 \cdots.
  \end{cases} \\
  B &= \begin{cases}
    \rlap{$\zeta_{A}$}\phantom{\zeta_B} = \phantom{1{,}001}\llap{$-10$}.1234567 \cdots, \\
    \zeta_B = 1{,}001.2345678 \cdots.
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

With `siunitx` and its powerful features for printing numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\newenvironment{xcases}[2][]
 {\left\lbrace\def\arraystretch{1.2}% like cases does
  \begin{array}{
    @{} r @{}
    >{{}}c<{{}} @{}
    S[table-format=#2,table-space-text-post={#1}] @{}
  }}
 {\end{array}\right.}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{xcases}[$\,\cdots$,]{4.7}
\zeta_A &=& -10.1234567$\,\cdots$, \\
\zeta_B &=& 1001.2345678$\,\cdots$.
\end{xcases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{xcases}{-4.7}
\zeta_A &=& -1001.1234567 \\
\zeta_B &=&  1001.2345678
\end{xcases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The mandatory argument is the number format; in the first case four digits for the integral part and seven for the fractional part. Also some text can be added, the optional argument is a literal text that specifies the allotted space. In the second case, four digits and the sign for the integral part.

[image]

Comment: To replicate the "look" specified by the OP a bit more closely, you could set the options `group-digits=integer`, `group-four-digits=true`, and `group-separator={,}` when loading `siunitx`.

Comment: @Mico Separating thousands with a comma is forbidden by my religion. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use of tabular with `@{.}` skill as an alternative. Further Mico's kind reminder: use of array.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath,array}


\begin{document}
Given

\[
\begin{cases}
{\zeta}_{A} = -10.1234567 \cdots, \\
{\zeta}_{B} = 1{,}001.2345678 \cdots.
\end{cases}
\]

Suggested
\[
\begin{cases}
\begin{tabular}{ >{$}r<{$} @{ = } >{$} r <{$} @{.} >{$}l<{$}}
{\zeta}_{A} &  -10    & 1234567 \cdots, \\
{\zeta}_{B} & 1{,}001 & 2345678 \cdots.
\end{tabular}
\end{cases}
\]

@Mico's credits

\[
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{ r @{ = }  r  @{.} l}
{\zeta}_{A} &  -10     & 1234567 \cdots, \\
{\zeta}_{B} & 1{,}001&2345678 \cdots.
\end{array}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ha, thanks Mico, you are quite right. I knew something can be improved, just can not think of it. will add one more option. soon.

Comment: In the `array` example, you should specify `@{{}={}}` rather than `@{ = }` to get an amount of spacing that's appropriate for an item of type `mathrel`. (`@{ = }` treats `=` as being of type `mathord`.)

Comment: Yes, indeed. You have shown that. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Here I use the `tabstackengine` package.  The OP's example can be done with a `\tabbedCenterstack`, though I then show a slightly more difficult version that requires a `\tabularCenterstack`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\setstackEOL{\#}% end-of-line character in stack
\setstackTAB{\&}% end-of-field character in stack
\setstackgap{L}{16pt}% Inter-baseline gap in stack
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}% Inter-field gap in tabularstack
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\tabbedCenterstack[r]{\zeta_{A} =\& -10.\&1234567 \cdots,\#
                      \zeta_{B} =\& 1,001.\&2345678 \cdots.}%
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\tabularCenterstack{rrl}{\zeta_{AC} =\& -10.\&1234 \cdots,\#
                      \zeta_{B} =\& 1,001.\&2345678 \cdots.}%
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to use the tabstackengine example and I am using TexShop on a Mac.  I can't properly install the package.  Any suggestions.

Comment: @menkelh The package is at http://ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine.  If you download the .sty file in your working directory it should compile.  In the long run, you need to find out where TeXShop stores its downloaded packages and put it there.  (I myself use MikTeX, and so I am of no help for that).  The PDF documentation is also available at the ctan site.