# Aligning equations in \begin{cases}

Tags: align, cases

I need neither of the following:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} 
ab =st \\ 
a-b =s+t 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} 
ab &=st \\ 
a-b &=s+t 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Instead, I want something like this with bracket on the left:

```
 ab=st
a-b=s+t
```

How to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219506/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{} r @{{}={}} l}
ab &st\\
a-b &s+t 
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to emulate `cases`, add `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` after `\left\{`.

Comment: if loading `mathtools, it's redundant to load `amsmath`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! (I know that but I feel it's "fairer" to load a package that defines the macro I am using.)